# How to archive files under certain dir that are not text files in Mac OS?

Tags: macos, bash, zip, terminal, archive

Hey, guys, I used zip command, but I only want to archive all the files except *.txt. For example, if two dirs file1, file2; both of them have some *.txt files. I want archive only the non-text ones from file1 and file2.

tl;dr: How to tell linux to give me all the files that don't match *.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move to you desired directory and run:

```
ls | grep -P '\.(?!txt$)' | zip -@ zipname
```

This will create a `zipname.zip` file containing everything but `.txt` files. In short, what it does is:

1. List all files in the directory, one per line (this can be achieved by using the `-1` option, however it is not needed here as it's the default when output is not the terminal, it is a pipe in this case).
2. Extract from that all lines that do not end in `.txt`. Note it's `grep` using a Perl regular expression (option `-P`) so the negative lookahead can be used.
3. Zip the list from stdin (`-@`) into `zipname` file.

---

### Update

The first method I posted fails with files with two `.`, like I described in the comments. For some reason though, I forgot about the `-v` option for grep which prints only what *doesn't* match the regex. Plus, go ahead and include a case insensitive option.

```
ls | grep -vi '\.txt$' | zip -@ zipname
```

Comment: By the way, the regular expression will match files like `text.new.txt`. These will be included in the zip. If you have files like this then let me know to build a bigger expression...

Comment: If you are going to use this method I'm surprised no-one has suggested find: `$ find . -type f ! -iname '*.txt' -exec zip zipfile {} \;`.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ zip -r zipfile -x'*.txt' folder1 folder2 ...
```

Comment: This is the way to go, better than my extglob soln since it's buitin to `zip`

Answer (score 0):

Simple, use bash's Extended Glob option like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

zip -some -options !(*.txt)
```

#### Edit

This isn't as good as the `-x` builtin option to `zip` but my solution is generic across any command that may not have this nice feature.